# Can I request (request.getParameter) a parameter that has been previously requested?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, jstl

Say I have Form A, B & confirmation.jsp which holds no form.

Form A has the initial parameter:

```
<input class="likes" name="likes" readonly type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${likes}"/>"/>
```

Form B requests the parameter from A:

```
<input class="likes" name="likes" readonly type="text" value="<%= request.getParameter("likes")%>"/>
```

confirmation.jsp requests the parameter from B, to display the info on the page:

```
 <c:set var="likedProduct" value="<%= request.getParameter("likes")%>"/> 
<c:out value="likedProduct"/>
```

Strangely, Form A & B hold the inputs perfectly fine. I switched it from `hidden` to `text` to see if the variables were there in the first place and yest they are.

But confirmation.jsp does not display the variable. It is blank with not even `null`, just pure nada. How come?

Comment: Do you submit form A to the page that contains form B? Is confirmation.jsp the action of form B? In other words is form B submitted to confirmation.jsp ?  The reason I ask is that your wording "confirmation.jsp requests the parameter from B" is confusing.

Comment: @rickz: Thanks for your input rickz. The answer is Yes to all of the above. But it is solved. For some reason using `c:out` does not work but using the function let alone works like this `${likedProduct}`. I have no reason why but when it works that is what matters for me lol.

Comment: Try using <c:out value="${likedProduct}"/>